# Send mail from Microsoft Teams bot

Tags: python, email, smtp, bots, microsoft-teams

I am developing a bot that will help with solving routine problems. One of its functionalities, i want to make sending the problem to the mail.

I have written a code to send a message. It works locally, but not in MS Teams bot.

```
email = "my_email"
help_email = "help_mail"

message = MIMEText(turn_context.activity.text)
message["Subject"] = turn_context.activity.text
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.office365.com', 587)
server.ehlo()
server.starttls()
server.sendmail(email, help_email, message.as_string())
await turn_context.send_activity("Send!")
server.quit()
help = False
return await self._send_suggested_actions(turn_context)
```

Error: `Name or service not known`

Please tell me how to fix this problem, or suggest a better solution (i'm sure there is).

Thank you!

Comment: As per my knowledge, Microsoft Teams itself does not natively support sending emails through a bot directly. 
you could create a bot that interacts with Microsoft Outlook APIs or other email service APIs to send emails on behalf of users. This would involve building a custom integration between your bot and the chosen email service.
Reference document-https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-sendmail?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp
2.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/outlook-things-to-know-about-send-mail